# Multilingual interface with FoxPro

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm having trouble implementing a multilingual interface with FoxPro.

I'm storing the translations in a MySQL database and try to load them into an array (through a cursor and sqlexcel), which in turn display in the appropriate places.

However, the non-ANSI characters (e.g. French diacritics) become question marks. No STRCONV and CPCONVERT help, because the characters are already lost in the cursor.

I also tried storing the translations in a text file, and reading it with STRTOFILE. That doesn't work either - regardless of the file encoding (tried UTF-8, tried windows-1252). STRCONV on the result of STRTOFILE is doing weird things and turns the special characters into other special characters and/or question marks.

Note: My OS default encoding is likely 1251. I've set CODEPAGE = 1252 in config.fpw. Still no luck.

Is there a way to support different code pages in the same application?

Comment: I don't know how far into this effort you are, but take a look at Steven Black's INTL Toolkit instead: http://stevenblack.com/intl/